# Generate own app album to save images from camera just like Messenger and Whatsapp app

Tags: android, camera

I would like to generate dedicated album for my application in gallery when users capture photos using camera in my application. This album will used to save all images that captured from camera intent inside my application. It works just like the Messenger and Whatsapp app. Anyone know how to do this?

```
public class ImageQueryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout mImageQueryLayout;
    private ImageView mAddPhotoButton;
    private String mCurrentPhotoPath;

    final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_GALLERY = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_query);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mImageQueryLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_query_layout);
        mAddPhotoButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add_photo_image_view);
        mAddPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    // dp to pixel converter
    public static int convDpToPx(Context context, float dp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, metrics);
    }

    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageQueryActivity.this);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Problem occurred while saving photo",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                                "com.kelvin.foodizzy.fileprovider",
                                photoFile);
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        galleryAddPic(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*").setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), REQUEST_GALLERY);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                        (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                convDpToPx(getApplicationContext(), 180));
                layoutParams.setMargins(layoutParams.leftMargin, layoutParams.topMargin,
                        layoutParams.rightMargin, convDpToPx(getApplicationContext(), 20));
                imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath));
                galleryAddPic(mCurrentPhotoPath);
                mImageQueryLayout.addView(imageView);
            }
        }
    }

    private void galleryAddPic(String file) {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(file);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }

}
```

Comment: You're basically asking how to create a folder.

Comment: I would like to save images also. Currently I still cannot get my images in Photos app.
The following is my file_paths.xml:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="my_images"
        path="Android/data/com.kelvin.foodizzy/files/Pictures" />
</paths>

Comment: If you create a folder (programmatically) on the storage, it can be then accessed by the MediaScanner. And your pictures will be automatically found.

Comment: Where is the correct place to put galleryAddPic() method?

Comment: What you call "album" is just a folder. That's how Whatsapp (and Telegram, and the Camera, ...) works. The MediaScanner will fetch the pictures from any folder, unless they have been added to the exclusion list.

Comment: What can I do to the code above in order to save photos?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I manage to solve my problem. This work on API above 24

```
//set file storage to getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
    private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
            String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
            File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Foodizzy");
            if (!storageDir.exists()) {
                if (!storageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("Camera", "failed to create directory");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            File image = File.createTempFile(
                    imageFileName,
                    ".jpg",
                    storageDir
            );
            mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
            return image;
        }

//Inside camera intent, use file provider to get photo uri
Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent();
    takePictureIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);


    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
    try {
          photoFile = createImageFile();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (photoFile != null) {
        Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", photoFile);
        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
        }


//to store the image inside photo Gallery / (in my Nexus phone is Photos), create the following method
private void galleryAddPic() {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
        }

//and call the method inside onActivityResult
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
                //code to get bitmap or whatever
                galleryAddPic();

            }
        }
    }

    //Inside AndroidManifest.xml, add provider inside application
    <application
            ...
            ...>
            <provider
                android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
                android:exported="false"
                android:grantUriPermissions="true">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
            </provider>
    </application>

    //create a file named "file_paths.xml" under xml and add the following code
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <paths>
        <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```